# gRPC service for managing groups

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

Trying out gRPC for the first time in a few years and looking for some feedback on the simplest of the APIs, since no one is currently using it extensively at my company and will end up pioneering its use. The API is for managing groups, i.e. you have users with UIDs and groups with GIDs. A user can belong to any number of groups. Each user as a group member also needs to have binary metadata that is opaque to the service itself.

I've searched for various "best practices" docs and tried to incorporate all the necessary suggestions. This is for a pretty large-scale deployment, so especially advice on making the protos extensible for typical production issues would be helpful.

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/empty.proto";

package groups;

//
// Service description
//

service GroupService {
  rpc CreateGroup (CreateGroupRequest) returns (CreateGroupResponse) {}
  rpc DestroyGroup (DestroyGroupRequest) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
  rpc AddMembers (AddMembersRequest) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
  rpc RemoveMembers (RemoveMembersRequest) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
  rpc ListMembers (ListMembersRequest) returns (ListMembersResponse) {}
  rpc GetMetadata (GetMetadataRequest) returns (GroupMetadata) {}
  rpc SetMetadata (SetMetadataRequest) returns (google.protobuf.Empty) {}
}

//
// Generic messages
//

message Member {
  string id = 1;
  bytes metadata = 2;
}

message GroupMetadata {
  bool broadcast = 1;
  bool chat = 2;
}

//
// Protocol messages
//

message CreateGroupRequest {
  string namespace = 1;
  GroupMetadata metadata = 2;
}

message CreateGroupResponse {
  string namespace = 1;
  string gid = 2;
  GroupMetadata metadata = 3;
}

message DestroyGroupRequest {
  string namespace = 1;
  string gid = 2;
}

message AddMembersRequest {
  string namespace = 1;
  string gid = 2;
  repeated Member members = 3;
}

message RemoveMembersRequest {
  string namespace = 1;
  string gid = 2;
  repeated string members = 3;
}

message ListMembersRequest {
  string namespace = 1;
  string gid = 2;
}

message ListMembersResponse {
  repeated Member members = 1;
}

message GetMetadataRequest {
  string namespace = 1;
  string gid = 2;
}

message SetMetadataRequest {
  string namespace = 1;
  string gid = 2;
  GroupMetadata metadata = 3;
}
```